# Jira workflow for Android project

Tags: android, mobile, workflow, jira

Recently our company moved from daPulse to Jira for an better project management.
Currently I'm in the state of configuring the workflow for the Issues in Jira.

I've come up with the following diagram:

[image: Jira workflow diagram]

Can someone with more experience confirm that this workflow is ok and it won't create issues in the future ? I want to configure it now and avoid future changes and problems.

Also, is there a way to restrict some users from changing the status of an Issue ? For example I want to restrict Developers to make Code Reviews and/or Tests. Team Leaders should do Code Reviews and QA Team should do Tests. Is something like this doable in Jira environment ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict some users from changing the status of an issue, you can directly add a condition on your transition between two status.
This condition can be a restriction by group (i.e. only users from a certain group can execute the transition) or by role.

Comment: I've read something like this on Jira documentation, but it was a little confusing. Now that you confirmed that it is possible like this I will definitely investigate more and try to configure something like this.
Thank you.